# Java, why collections.sort() still works with non-comparator typed argument?

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I know in java Collections class, there is a static method sort:

```
sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c**)
```

The second argument in sort should be an object which implements **Comparator** interface and it's compare method.

But when I learn **lambda's method reference**, I see this example:

```
public class Test 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Test().sortWord();  
    }

    public void sortWord()
    {
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.add("hello");
        lst.add("world");
        lst.add("apple");
        lst.add("zipcode");

        Collections.sort(lst, this::compareWord);

        System.out.println(lst);
    }

    public int compareWord(String a, String b)
    {
       return a.compareTo(b);
    }
```

}

This is an example of method reference for instance method.
the compareWord method has nothing to do with the Comparator interface, I can not understand why this works? can anyone explain this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int compareWord(String a, String b)` has the same signature as the `int compare(String o1, String o2)` method of the `Comparator<String>` interface. Therefore it can be used as an implementation of that interface.

This is a shorter way of writing:

```
Collections.sort(lst, new Comparator<String> () {
                     public int compare (String o1, String o2) {
                         return compareWord(o1,o2);
                     }
                 });
```

In Java 8 any functional interface such as `Comparator` (i.e. interface having a single abstract method) can be implemented with a method reference of a method having a signature matching the signature of that interface's abstract method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a explicit String Comparator here.

Just do following and it should work fine.

```
Collections.sort(lst);
```

By the way @Eran has explained, same method signature about compareWord and compare in your scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface is a [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8):

> A functional interface is an interface that [...] represents a single function contract. [...]
>
> For an interface I, let M be the set of abstract methods that are members of I that do not have the same signature as any public instance method of the class Object. Then, I is a functional interface if there exists a method m in M for which both of the following are true:
>
> - The signature of m is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of every method's signature in M.
> - m is return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for every method in M.
>
> In addition to the usual process of creating an interface instance by declaring and instantiating a class ([§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)), instances of functional interfaces can be created with method reference expressions and lambda expressions ([§15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13), [§15.27](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)).

It further mentions `Comparator` as an example:

> The definition of functional interface excludes methods in an interface that are also public methods in Object. This is to allow functional treatment of an interface like java.util.Comparator that declares multiple abstract methods of which only one is really "new" - int compare(T,T). The other method - boolean equals(Object) - is an explicit declaration of an abstract method that would otherwise be implicitly declared, and will be automatically implemented by every class that implements the interface.

Beside the anonymous class example provided by @Eran and the method reference expression from the question, a lamba expression would work too:

```
Collections.sort(lst, (a, b) -> ...);
```